# Stock screener from Sentdex

Tags: python, numpy, yahoo-finance

I am trying to replicate Sentdex's stock screener he uploaded as a tutorial back in 2013 (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y4GHgJjIQnk). Unfortunately, a lot of things changed since then, so minor adjustments to the code he proposed are to be made. I post the part of the code which is not working properly only here below. The entire code is available following the link above, if anybody is interested.

The code, essentially the original one with some minor exceptions regarding the yahoo url method, is the following:

```
import urllib.request
import time
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import mpl_finance
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib
import pylab
```

...

```
def graphData(stock,MA1,MA2):

    '''
        Use this to dynamically pull a stock:
    '''
    try:
        print('Currently Pulling',stock)
        urlToVisit = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/'+stock+'?interval=2m'
        stockFile =[]
        try:
            sourceCode = urllib.request.urlopen(urlToVisit).read().decode()
            splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')
            for eachLine in splitSource:
                splitLine = eachLine.split(',')
                if len(splitLine)==6:
                    if 'values' not in eachLine:
                        stockFile.append(eachLine)
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(e), 'failed to organize pulled data.')
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e), 'failed to pull pricing data')

    try:
        date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(stockFile,delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters={0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})
```

The output I get is the following:

```
Currently Pulling ABT
UserWarning: loadtxt: Empty input file: "[]"
  date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(stockFile,delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters={0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})
list assignment index out of range
Currently Pulling ABBV
main loop list assignment index out of range
```

...etc for all the tickers in the sp500 list specified after all the relevant imports.

Any idea what is wrong? The link I am trying to extract information from is the following: https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/AAPL?interval=2m

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the way you process the response from `Yahoo`, more precisely :

`splitSource = sourceCode.split('\n')` it doesn't do as you think, the best and easiest way to process the ouput, is by using `json.loads()` since Yahoo output is already under `json` format:

```
import urllib.request
import time
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import mpl_finance
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib
import pylab, json
...

def graphData(stock,MA1,MA2):

    '''
        Use this to dynamically pull a stock:
    '''
    try:
        print('Currently Pulling',stock)
        urlToVisit = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/'+stock+'?interval=2m'
        print(urlToVisit)
        stockFile =[]
        try:
            sourceCode = urllib.request.urlopen(urlToVisit).read().decode()
            sourceCode = json.loads(sourceCode)
            print(sourceCode['chart']['result'][0]['indicators']['quote'][0].keys())
            #dict_keys(['low', 'close', 'open', 'high', 'volume'])
...
```

> Just by browsing the nested dictionary `json.loads` returns, you can obtain any data and in the order you like :

```
stock = "FB"
print('Currently Pulling',stock)
urlToVisit = 'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/'+stock+'?interval=2m'
print(urlToVisit)
stockFile =[]
sourceCode = urllib.request.urlopen(urlToVisit).read().decode()
sourceCode = json.loads(sourceCode)
resp_ = {}
resp_ = sourceCode['chart']['result'][0]['indicators']['quote'][0]
resp_['timestamp'] = sourceCode['chart']['result'][0]['timestamp']
print(resp_.keys())
#dict_keys(['close', 'open', 'timestamp', 'volume', 'high', 'low'])
```

and the timestamps for each value.

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately, it is still not working for me. The error I get now is: 
`
string indices must be integers failed to organize pulled data.
UserWarning: loadtxt: Empty input file: "[]"
  date, closep, highp, lowp, openp, volume = np.loadtxt(stockFile,delimiter=',', unpack=True, converters={0: bytespdate2num('%Y%m%d')})
main loop list assignment index out of range
`
And, most annoyingly, the whole json yahoo file is now printed as an output before this!

Comment: By using json you don't need to unpack anymore, ok let me give you the full version in few minutes

Comment: I am sorry, I am a rather noobish user :D

Comment: I added an example that give you a simple dictionary to browse by using simple keys, btw my previous answer had a small typo you must have `sourceCode = json.loads(sourceCode)` not `SplitSource = json...`, I fixed it in my updated answer, be sure to accept my answer ;)

Comment: I would be extremely happy to accept you answer, but the solution you propose does not really work for me... I tried to implement your solutions, but I came out with more errors, like "HTTP Error 404: Not Found failed to organize pulled data." or "
main loop list assignment index out of range". I also tried to run separately your example, but it yielded: "Currently Pulling FB
https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v8/finance/chart/FB?interval=2m
dict_keys(['volume', 'low', 'high', 'open', 'close', 'timestamp'])"